# Simple K8s Pod checks using Shell script

Tags: bash

I'm using simple base script to check the k8s pod health check status running or not. Below script running as expected from default namespace, but I want to check the pod status across all the namespace inside my cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash 

# colores
blanc="\033[1;37m"
gray="\033[0;37m"
magento="\033[0;35m"
red="\033[1;31m"
green="\033[1;32m"
amarillo="\033[1;33m"
azul="\033[1;34m"
rescolor="\e[0m"

listPods=$(kubectl get po | awk 'NR>1{print $1}')
#echo "$listPods"
readarray  arr <<<  $listPods

ok=0
notok=0
echo -e "\nSit Down and Wait  \U1F602 :\n"
for i in ${arr[@]}
do 
echo -ne "$i ... " 
status=$(kubectl get po $i | grep $i | awk '{print $3}')
    if [[ ! $status =~ ^Running$|^Completed$  ]]  ; then
        echo -e "\e[1;31mOh Shit !"$rescolor""
        notify-send "Pods Health" "$i was  Checked" -t 10000 
        let notok=notok+1
    else
        echo -e "\e[1;32mOK!"$rescolor""
        #notify-send "Pod $i Is Good :)"
      let ok=ok+1
    fi
done
echo -e "\nSTATS:\n"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
printf  "|$green%-15s$rescolor|$red%-15s$rescolor|\n" "Healthy Pods" "Unhealthy Pods"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
printf  "|%-15s|%-15s|\n" "$ok" "$notok"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
echo -e "\n"
```

Comment: Replace `kubectl get pod` with `kubectl get pod -A` to get all pods from all namespaces. Does that get you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all try to retrieve the list of namespaces using the `kubectl get namespaces` and then, iterate over each namespace and retrieve the pods in that namespace using `kubectl get po -n $ns`!

something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# colors
blanc="\033[1;37m"
gray="\033[0;37m"
magento="\033[0;35m"
red="\033[1;31m"
green="\033[1;32m"
amarillo="\033[1;33m"
azul="\033[1;34m"
rescolor="\e[0m"

namespaces=$(kubectl get namespaces -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')

ok=0
notok=0
echo -e "\nSit Down and Wait  \U1F602 :\n"
for ns in ${namespaces[@]}
do
    echo -e "Namespace: $ns"
    listPods=$(kubectl get po -n $ns | awk 'NR>1{print $1}')
    readarray arr <<< $listPods

    for i in ${arr[@]}
    do
        echo -ne "$i ... "
        status=$(kubectl get po -n $ns $i | grep $i | awk '{print $3}')
        if [[ ! $status =~ ^Running$|^Completed$ ]]; then
            echo -e "\e[1;31mOh Shit !"$rescolor""
            notify-send "Pods Health" "$i was Checked" -t 10000
            let notok=notok+1
        else
            echo -e "\e[1;32mOK!"$rescolor""
            #notify-send "Pod $i Is Good :)"
            let ok=ok+1
        fi
    done
done

echo -e "\nSTATS:\n"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
printf "|$green%-15s$rescolor|$red%-15s$rescolor|\n" "Healthy Pods" "Unhealthy Pods"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
printf "|%-15s|%-15s|\n" "$ok" "$notok"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
echo -e "\n"
```

Comment: Thank you so much above iteration working fine as expected, thanks lot again.